# Set button action dynamically

Tags: iphone, button, selector

I have a few buttons in my view which work as a slideshow, every few seconds buttons change their appearance. On button click I open UIWebView and load a page, I need to change the target (url) of each button when they change their appearance.

What is the easiest way to do it? I can't change buttons' tags as my slideshow based on them.

Comment: Can you post some code, I have some solutions in my head but not so sure if it fits your questions. I want some code about the way you init the button,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the url in an @property of the ViewController and update it when you update the button's appearance.